# how to get url in product page with product name?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

https://example.com/magentoce1.8/index.php/furniture.html ,like the above formated

i tried mage::getUrl() but not getting desired output

Answer (score 1):

If you have the product id you can try this:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);

$url = $product->getProductUrl();
```

And make sure your url rewrites index us up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$product->getProductUrl(true);
```